# post-increment operator and pre-decrement operator to the same variable in c

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why ++*p++ works while ++i++ does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072407/why-p-works-while-i-does-not)

Is this possible in c?If not what is the reason?

```
int main()
{
  char *p="hai friends";
   while(*p!='\0')
   {
      ++*p++;
      printf("%c\n",*p);
   }
}
```

Comment: Trivia aside, please never do this in production code!

Comment: yes of course..just for understanding c and workings of compiler

Comment: Note that this particular example wouldn't terminate, even if it didn't modify a string literal, since `*(p+length)` will be modified and won't evaluate to `\0` anymore.

Comment: There's no "post-increment operator and pre-decrement operator to the same variable" in your code.

Answer (score 3):

This particular example

```
char *p="hai friends";
while(*p!='\0')
{
    ++*p++;
    printf("%c\n",*p);
}
```

attempts to modify a string literal and is thus undefined behaviour. But in general, for a pointer, you can do

```
++*p++;
```

since the post- and the pre-increment refer to different entities. The post-increment increments *the pointer* while the pre-increment increments the pointed-to value.

Using pre- and post-decrement on the same entity would again cause undefined behaviour, since that would modify a variable twice without intervening sequence point.

Comment: Exactly right. (+1) for mentioning modifying const data. I'd also put braces to stress the operator order.